# Pure HTML and CSS client-side form

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there a css/HTML combo I could use to create a client-side-only form?

Say a text box at the top of the form, the user writes a name in the text box. Then for every class="name" element, the text for that element is changed to the user's entry. I can do this with JavaScript/php, but I'd like this to be only dependent upon HTML/css.

Can this be done with :after contents and display:grid?

Comment: If you want to manipulate DOM elements and change their text based on the user's input in another element, you'll need JS. No way around it.

Comment: You'll need js to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only mechanism for setting the value of an input in HTML is the `value` attribute, which isn't dependant on user input.

CSS has no means to set the value of an input.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is a "thing that should not be" but I was just wondering if I might be missing out on some way to do it all client side without JavaScript.